# Get class object from object.toString in java

Tags: java

I want to get the class object from the `object.toString` (without overriding the toString method in the class).

I know the reflection will give the object but it creates a new instance of the class which I don't want.

Comment: i don't understand the question...

Comment: You can use the method `Object.getClass()`

Comment: neither do I.  Do you want to get a `string` that contains the name of your class?

Comment: `toString()` does not generate something intended for a computer to work with.

Comment: Perhaps you are getting confused with newInstance() method which will create a new instance.

Answer (score 8):

> I know the reflection will give the object but it creates a new instance of the class which I don't want.

No, it really won't.

Just call

```
foo.getClass();
```

instead of

```
foo.toString();
```

That most certainly *won't* create a new instance of the class. It will just get a `Class` reference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes..you will get the Class object from `toString()` **without overloading** it.. but it will be in the form of `getClass().getName()+"@"+hashCode();`'

so `obj.getClass();` will do the magic for you, and will likely to be handing over you the `Reference` of the `Class` ..............